# lenovo yoga 300 hard drive error to boot ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, lenovo

I have a laptop Lenovo yoga 300-11 and I'm having trouble installing ubuntu. I'm booting perfectly fine from the usb and everything works perfect with the installation but when the laptop is restarting then it says that it cant see the hard drive to boot and open Ubuntu. Thanks is advance.

Comment: How old is your computer, and how did you get Ubuntu on the flash drive? This may be a UFEI/legacy BIOS issue. Try using the Rufus tool to create the bootable flash drive.

Comment: My pc is 3 years old. We used Rufus to create the usb bootable.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the error message or the exact text?

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me :). Today ( a few hours ago) i found the reason why i couldnt boot from my hard drive. I made an experiment and tried to install ubuntu x64 and it worked perfect with the first attempt. As it seems my hard drive couldnt accept x86 only x64. So now it works just fine :) thanks again Soupy and im sorry for the trouble i may caused you.

Comment: No problem. I suggest powering that as an answer and accepting it.

Comment: Umm how? As u can see im new to this.